# Create a surface plot of xyz altitude data

Tags: python, surface, geography, topography

I am trying to create a surface plot of a mountain in python, of which I have some xyz data. The end result should look something like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKQV0.png). The file is formatted as follows:

```
616000.0 90500.0 3096.712
616000.0 90525.0 3123.415
616000.0 90550.0 3158.902
616000.0 90575.0 3182.109
616000.0 90600.0 3192.991
616025.0 90500.0 3082.684
616025.0 90525.0 3116.597
616025.0 90550.0 3149.812
616025.0 90575.0 3177.607
616025.0 90600.0 3191.986
```

and so on. The first column represents the `x` coordinate, the middle one the `y` coordinate, and `z` the altitude that belongs to the xy coordinate.

I read in the data using `pandas` and then convert the columns to individual `x`, `y`, `z` `NumPy` 1D arrays. So far I managed to create a simple 3D scatter plot with a `for` loop iterating over each index of each 1D array, but that takes ages and makes the appearance of being quite inefficient.

I've tried to work with `scipy.interpolate.griddata` and `plt.plot_surface`, but for `z` data I always get the error that data should be in a 2D array, but I cannot figure out why or how it should be 2D data. I assume that given I have xyz data, there should be a way to simply create a surface from it. Is there a simple way?

Answer (score 8):

Using functions [`plot_trisurf`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#tri-surface-plots) and [`scatter`](https://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/mplot3d/tutorial.html#scatter-plots) from `matplotlib`, given `X Y Z` data can be plotted similar to [given plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKQV0.png).

```py
import sys
import csv
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import axes3d

# Read CSV
csvFileName = sys.argv[1]
csvData = []
with open(csvFileName, 'r') as csvFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=' ')
    for csvRow in csvReader:
        csvData.append(csvRow)

# Get X, Y, Z
csvData = np.array(csvData)
csvData = csvData.astype(np.float)
X, Y, Z = csvData[:,0], csvData[:,1], csvData[:,2]

# Plot X,Y,Z
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, color='white', edgecolors='grey', alpha=0.5)
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='red')
plt.show()
```

Here,

- file containing `X Y Z` data provided as argument to above script
- in `plot_trisurf`, parameters used to control appearance. e.g. `alpha` used to control opacity of surface
- in `scatter`, `c` parameter specifies color of points plotted on surface

For given data file, following plot is generated

[image]

*Note:* Here, the terrain is formed by triangulation of given set of 3D points. Hence, contours along surface in plot are not aligned to X- and Y- axes

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d 
import pandas as pd 
 
df = pd.read_csv("/content/1.csv") 
X = df.iloc[:, 0] 
Y = df.iloc[:, 1] 
Z = df.iloc[:, 2] 
 
fig = plt.figure() 
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d') 
ax.plot_trisurf(X, Y, Z, color='white', edgecolors='grey', alpha=0.5) 
ax.scatter(X, Y, Z, c='red') 
plt.show()
```

**My output image below - I had a lot of data points:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu4PA.png)

Answer (score 0):

There is  an easier way to achieve your goal without using pandas.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d

x, y = np.mgrid[-2 : 2 : 20j, -2 : 2 : 20j]
z = 50 * np.sin(x + y)                     # test data
output = plt.subplot(111, projection = '3d')   # 3d projection
output.plot_surface(x, y, z, rstride = 2, cstride = 1, cmap = plt.cm.Blues_r)
output.set_xlabel('x')                         # axis label
output.set_xlabel('y')
output.set_xlabel('z')

plt.show()
```

[image: plot example]

Comment: hi thanks for your answer. When I try to use my x,y,z data, it also says that Z must be 2-dimensional. My z data are altitude values, so they cant be computed by inputs x and y.