# Python 3D surface plot by only having X, Y, Z coordinates

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, plot, surface

Is there anyway to plot surface in Python by only having X, Y, Z coordinates?

I have column vectors of X, Y, Z values where Z=F(X,Y) is already calculated ( I only have the data not the function )

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (12,10))
ax = plt.axes(projection='3d')

x = np.arange(-5, 5.1, 0.2)
y = np.arange(-5, 5.1, 0.2)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z = np.sin(X)*np.cos(Y)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, cmap = plt.cm.cividis)

# Set axes label
ax.set_xlabel('x', labelpad=20)
ax.set_ylabel('y', labelpad=20)
ax.set_zlabel('z', labelpad=20)

fig.colorbar(surf, shrink=0.5, aspect=8)

plt.show()
```

Examples like above in the manual consider that you can calculate Z = np.sin(X)*np.cos(Y)

But I cannot do that since I don't have the function.

Is there anyway to plot surface with only having X, Y, Z values in Python?

Comment: @Tom The problem is the Z shape. Run the example code provided. Print(Z)
My Z shape is column vector of F(X,Y) values.

Comment: Gotcha, sorry I see that now!  Will look a little more

Comment: You don't need to have a Z-function for `ax.plot_surface`. But you need to have Z-values for each point of a 2D grid of X-Y values. Note that `np.meshgrid(x, y)` in the example code creates a 2D grid out of 2 1D arrays, and therefore Z is a 2D array of values. If you have ungridded XYZ values, you can use [`ax.plot_trisurf`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51891538/create-a-surface-plot-of-xyz-altitude-data-in-python)

Comment: @JohanC Is trisurf the only way? is not there any hack to be able to use plot_surface?

Comment: Why? You could create some triangulation and interpolate Z-Values for a regular grid. Lots of work to emulate the out-of-the-box `ax.plot_trisurf`. However, if your X and Y values are already situated on a regular grid, `ax.plot_surface` would be the way to go.  Your post doesn't contain enough information to help here.

Comment: You could as well as replace ``Z = np.sin(X)*np.cos(Y)`` with ``Z = np.random.rand(len(x),len(y))`` and the code will still plot just fine. The Z values don't necessarily have to be a function of X and Y

Comment: @Karina Well I have got a Z value and I want to plot that specific Z value not some random matrix!

Comment: basically, I was saying: even random would work, why wouldn't yours? Just replace this line ``Z = np.sin(X)*np.cos(Y)`` with your specific Z value. It doesn't matter.

Comment: @Karina A column vector of Z values won't work.

Comment: why don't you just post your sample data in the question?

Comment: @Karina My sample data is (N, 3) matrix where N is arbitrary. Column1 is x, column2 is y, column 3 is z. In the code above I've posted as an example use of plot_surface if you print(Z) you will see that it returns a matrix but I have a column of Z values not a matrix and that's where the problem lies. I cannot use plot_surface because of that.

Comment: Well, I say it could work. ``Z = np.tile(z, (len(x), 1))`` will do the trick. In this case, ``z`` has the shape like yours.